# Есть простой INSERT. Как сделать проверку при записи двух полей, что если в 2 строках совпадают 2 столбца, то не записывать?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Таблица supports_user:

```
id    |   support_id   |   client_id
1     |          2        |       13
2     |          2        |       13

$query1 = "INSERT INTO supports_user (support_id, client_id) VALUES ('$support_id', '$client_id')";
```

Как избежать такого дублирования? Что если есть такой `support_id` с таким же `client_id`, то не записывать?

Comment: сделайте уникальный индекс состоящий из этих двух полей

Comment: не подскажите как это сделать или где почитать про это можно?

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл как сделать

```
ALTER TABLE supports_user  ADD UNIQUE KEY (support_id, client_id);
```